# how to close specific file programmatically in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to close a file programmatically which is opened.

What is the command for Close editor `Ctrl+F4`

I tried below with no success

```js
let mdfile = filename_noext + ".md";
let uri = vscode.Uri.file(mdfile);
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeFolder", uri);
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeFolder", mdfile);
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor", uri);
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeEditorsInGroup", uri);
```

`workbench.action.closeActiveEditor` closes current editor but I want close specific editor in all opened editors.

As a work around I did  below since for now I know I want close previous editor.

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.previousEditor");
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor");
```

Also could not get anything helpful here at the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands)

Comment: related and potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73936365/11107541 (I've written an answer there)

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to directly close a file by URI or other reference. As a workaround, the API provides the ability to close the active editor:

```
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor")
```

or if you want to close a document that is not saved and bypass the save-prompt, you may use this command:

```
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.revertAndCloseActiveEditor")
```

You can make a TextDocument active by using this command:

```
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.open", textDocumentToClose.uri)
```

Putting it together, you can make the document you want to close active and then close it:

```
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.open", textDocumentToClose.uri)
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor")
//or await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.revertAndCloseActiveEditor")
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar, and after a *lot* of reading here and in the VS Code Issues, I came up with the solution below.  A key point for me, is that when I initially open the file I use: vscode.ViewColumn.Beside, and this code allows me to find the file in any View Column.

```
export async function closeAnyOpenErrorFiles () {
  
  // this funciton will close any left over ACOMPILE.LIS or AALINKER.LIS files 
  // from the last test execution.
  for (let editor of vscode.window.visibleTextEditors) {
    if (editor.document.fileName.endsWith ("ACOMPILE.LIS") || editor.document.fileName.endsWith ("AALINKER.LIS")) {
      await vscode.window.showTextDocument(editor.document.uri, 
        { preview: false, viewColumn: editor.viewColumn, });     
      await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor");
    }
  }
}
```