# Is there a VS Code API function to close a TextDocument?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do you close a Text Document (`vscode.TextDocument`) in VSCode after it has been opened with `vscode.workspace.openTextDocument`?

I am trying to find all the files in a workspace that have been tagged with a specific languageid, but the only way to achieve that is by getting the file URI and opening it as a `TextDocument`. I would then want to dispose that `TextDocument`.

FYI: `openTextDocument` loads the URI into memory and **is not** the same as `vscode.window.showTextDocument` which displays the document in the editor.
**Therefore**, [How to close TextDocument in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733028/how-to-close-textdocument-in-vs-code) **is not a duplicate!**

Answer (score 0):

I [asked the maintainers about this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187008) and [the response I got from Johannes Rieken](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187008#issuecomment-1621138679) was:

> We do support closing tabs/editor via `window.tabGroups.close` but we will not support to close documents because they are managed by VS Code itself

Note that `window.tabGroup.close` is mentioned in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75192905/11107541) to the other question post that you linked to.

Historically related discussion can also be found in the following issue tickets:

- [API Access to "Open Editors" #15178](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15178)
- [Extension API to close TextDocument #49740](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/49740)